# Neural Network Explainability when using Batch Normalization and Leaky ReLU

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, batch-normalization, shap

I recently learned about a NN explainable tool called Shapley Values.
For whoever is wondering, I train a dense neural network (although it can be done with CNNs and LSTMs too) and then use the following lines:

```
background = X[np.random.choice(X.shape[0], 10000, replace=False)]
e = shap.DeepExplainer(model_trained, background)
shap_values = e.shap_values(background)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[0], background, feature_names=cols_of_X, plot_type='dot',show=False)
```

The issue is that this only works for models that do not include batch normalization and leaky relus.

I know that I can just use
`tf.keras.Model(inputs = model_trained.layers[0].input,outputs=model_trained.layers[1].output)` instead of model_trained but then I'll only see how the first layer was affected by the input features and not how the output was affected by the input features.

Anyway have a way to overcome this or just use something other than Shapley?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add [reprex]

Comment: inp = tf.keras.Input((48))

l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='linear',kernel_initializer= initializer, bias_initializer= initializer)(inp)

l1 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3)(l1)

trained_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=l1)

and the rest of what I wrote earlier, thanks.